# how to cache XMLTYPE table in a TimesTen DB?

Tags: xml, oracle, caching, timesten

I have an XMLType table in an oracle database which I want to cache in a timesten cache group.  But because the constraint that the table definition in the cache group must be the same as in the oracle DB and the fact that the timesten database does not support xml data yet, I could not cache my table as it is. So I demand if someone has an idea how I could cache xml data in a timesten database?

Also I can't change the definition of the table. I know that caching XML data as a CLOB in a cache group is possible, but I don't want to change the definition of my table.

thanks

Comment: I don't think CLOBs *are* permitted in TimesTen.  The documentation doesn't mention them: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13085_01/doc/timesten.1121/e13070/index.htm#insertedID24   Do you actually need to use the XML?  Or is this just a constraint thang?

Comment: To add, the XMLType and CLOBs are explicitly not supported. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13085_01/doc/timesten.1121/e13076/dtypesfunc.htm#TTPLS190

Answer (score 1):

Oracle TimesTen supports LOB (CLOB, BLOB and NCLOB) types.

When a CLOB in Oracle is cached in TimesTen it will be mapped to a varchar2 type.
varchar2 in TimesTen can be up to 4 MB in size.

TimesTen does not natively support XMLType, so caching the XMLType column as a CLOB mapped to a varchar2 column is likely the best that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

No CLOB no XMLType but if it is sufficient for you: TimesTen `VARCHAR2` can hold up to 4,194,304 bytes.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13085_01/doc/timesten.1121/e13076/dtypesfunc.htm#BCGFBBJI